# Elasticsearch filter by year from a date field

Tags: elasticsearch

i have docs with date field of the format yyyy-MM-dd. is there a way to filter only based on year part of the field.

example:

```
{'name': 'a', 'born': '1984-11-22'},
{'name': 'b', 'born': '1984-12-12'},
{'name': 'c', 'born': '1985-10-22'},
```

I want to do a term/range filter to find people born on year 1984.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

```
"query": {
        "filtered": {
           "filter": {
               "range": {
                  "born": {
                     "gte": "1984||/y",
                     "lte": "1984||/y",
                     "format": "yyyy"
                  }
               }
           }
        }
    }
```

This required rounding the input year argument as well in addition to adding the format. Without rounding by year the range query does not work as intended. Tried it on multiple date formats like dateOptionalTime, date etc.

For details on how to use Date Math see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html

Comment: Only this works for me for elasticsearch 7.12. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it using a [`range` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-filter.html) and specifying a year `format` :

```
{
    "constant_score": {
        "filter": {
            "range" : {
                "born" : {
                    "gte": "1984",
                    "lte": "1984",
                    "format": "yyyy"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not correct, you need to use Date Math in order to query on the exact year, see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html

Comment: @Jaap Yes, as the other answer by the OP states

Comment: True, this was just to explain why this (previously upvoted) answer is not the correct one, as neither answer has been accepted by the OP.

Comment: @Val I want the exact range 1st January 2017 to 31st December 2017

Comment: @CarmenMitru feel free to ask a new question with your exact issue

Answer (score -1):

According to documentation, the solution will be:

```
GET _search
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "born" : {
                "gte": "1984",
                "lt": "1985",
                "format": "yyyy"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work, use `lte` instead of `lt`, or you condition will never be true.